dnspython does not resolve on osx inside corporate network
I am trying to use dnspython to resolve some names on our corporate network on mac osx.  There is the sample code I am using:
import dns.resolver

dns.resolver.default_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers = ['x.x.x.x']
dns.resolver.resolve('www.google.com')

x.x.x.x is replaced with the corporate dns server.  When run, the following error message is generated:
dns.resolver.LifetimeTimeout: The resolution lifetime expired after 5.402 seconds: Server Do53:135.37.9.16@53 answered The DNS operation timed out.

Using dig to make the query, I do get back valid results:
jon@laptop play3 % dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17452
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.103
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.106
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.105
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.147
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.104
www.google.com.     235 IN  A   74.125.21.99

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 06 09:25:51 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139

In the dig resopsone, I see the same name servers being used to do the lookup.  I have tried to adjust the timeout in python, using 8.8.8.8 as the dns server, and many other options including edns, but all changes result with same timeout exception.

For the dig command, to specify the server that you query, you must use the @server argument, e.g. dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com. Obviously, this won't fix your issue, but using dig @x.x.x.x www.google.com would be more reflective of your Python script...
dig docs ...
dig tutorial
